# Script to remove all inactive widgets?

Tags: plugin-development, widgets

I've been working with widgets a lot lately and have amassed a ton of widgets in the inactive widgets collection.

Can someone share a script or plugin that will remove all inactive widgets from the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like:

```
$widgets = get_option('sidebars_widgets');
$widgets['wp_inactive_widgets'] = array();
update_option('sidebars_widgets', $widgets);
```

Comment: @OTP: Works great. What if I want to remove ALL widgets?

Comment: then the second line should be `$widgets = array();` or just use `update_option('sidebars_widgets', array());`