# Remove the Inactive Widgets

Tags: widgets

I'm looking for a function, NOT A PLUGIN, that allow me to remove the Inactive Widgets... there was a topic before [Script to remove all inactive widgets?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/script-to-remove-all-inactive-widgets) with an answer, however it's not working for me.

Any other solutions?

Regards.!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function andrew_unregister_widgets() {
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Archives' );
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Calendar' );
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Categories' );
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Links' );
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Meta' );
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Pages' );
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Recent_Comments' );
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Recent_Posts' );
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_RSS' );
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Search' );
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Tag_Cloud' );
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Text' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'andrew_unregister_widgets()' );
```

This unregisters all in-built wordpress widgets. Which ones of those are already active you'd have to manually check and remove from the function before adding it to your *functions.php* file.

**EDIT:** Removing inactive widgets when the admin area loads:

```
function andrew_remove_inactive_widgets() {
    $widgets = get_option( 'sidebars_widgets' );
    $widgets['wp_inactive_widgets'] = array();
    update_option( 'sidebars_widgets', $widgets );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'andrew_remove_inactive_widgets' );
```

Comment: yeah I already have this one, however I'm looking to remove those which are below, the inactive widgets sections, I just added a pic of the exactly section, any ideas?

Comment: @andrewkthx Mkay. Updated the answer. Clears the section in question on my 3.2.1 dev install.

Comment: that's weird, that solution is similar to the post I mentioned before, however it doesn't work for me, I tried on 3 different environments w/o success